# How do you fix a docker image to run on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04, pocketmine

I am working on creating a Docker image to run PocketMine-MP. The only issue is that once it is built and I attempt to run the image it gives this output. (which means it is not compatible with my machine)

```
standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "exec format   error"
```

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04.. The following is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER Nathaniel Fredericks <me@nathfreder.website>

ARG POCKETMINE_BINARY=https://jenkins.pmmp.io/job/PHP-7.2-Linux-x86_64/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/PHP_Linux-x86_64.tar.gz
ARG POCKETMINE_ARCHIVE=https://jenkins.pmmp.io/job/PocketMine-MP/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/PocketMine-MP.phar
ARG POCKETMINE_START=https://rawgit.com/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/master/start.sh

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl

RUN curl ${POCKETMINE_BINARY} -o PHP_Linux-x86_64.tar.gz
RUN mkdir /root/server
RUN tar xf PHP_Linux-x86_64.tar.gz -C /root/server
RUN rm PHP_Linux-x86_64.tar.gz

WORKDIR "/root/server"

RUN curl ${POCKETMINE_ARCHIVE} -o PocketMine-MP.phar
RUN curl ${POCKETMINE_START} -o start.sh

RUN mkdir -p plugins
RUN mkdir -p players
RUN mkdir -p worlds
RUN mkdir -p resource_packs

RUN chmod +x ./start.sh

CMD ["./start.sh", "--no-wizard", "--disable-ansi"] # EDIT: This is the problem, the encoding is ASCII text.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your machine's CPU architecture? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @Yuankun 64-bit

Comment: I like your efford, but.. https://github.com/crscheid/pocketmine-mp ?

Comment: @ThomasSchwärzl This image is wrong, as it does not use the correct version of PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not related to your architecture, your link to start.sh is wrong.

The good one is

```
ARG POCKETMINE_START=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/master/start.sh
```

You had this error because your start.sh is actually this:

```
root@7787ad261644:~/server# cat start.sh 
<p>Moved Permanently. Redirecting to <a href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/master/start.sh">https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/master/start.sh</a></p>
```